# Find year of birth from given age in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

can somebody help me with this problem, I know I must use **sysdate**. For example I have entity EMPLOYEE with ATRIBUTES Emp.ID and Age.

Comment: Without their birthday, you could only narrow it down to one of two years, right?

Comment: Try `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')-age FROM employee`

Answer (score 1):

If we supply ADD_MONTHS with a negative number it subtracts that many months from the given date.  Multiplying the AGE by -12 gives us the number of months we need to subtract from the current date to derive the approximate birthday.

```
SELECT Emp.ID
       , TO_CHAR(
            ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, (Emp.Age*-12))
           , 'YYYY') as year_of_birth
FROM employee Emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not be accurate as exact month is not known

```
   SELECT id, Name, TRUNC(sysdate - age*365) as DOB FROM Employee
```